# How to calculate the count of data that gets duplicated in a SQL join?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I'm having trouble figuring out what type of join to use or if a join is even the correct way to go about this. I have two tables:

```
Patients Table

ID   | month_joined
--------------------
A110 | jan 2013 
A111 | feb 2013
A112 | april 2013

Appointments Table

ID   | month_of_appt | number_of_appts
--------------------------------------
A110 | jan 2013      |       2
A110 | feb 2013      |       1
A111 | april 2013    |       3
A112 | dec 2013      |       1
```

I want to be able to see the count of patients who joined in a given month (count of `month_joined` from Patients Table) and the number of appointments for each month (`number_of_appts` from Appointments Table). When I use a left join, the output looks like this:

```
Patients & Appointments

ID   | month_joined | month_of_appt | number_of_appts
-----------------------------------------------------
A110 | jan 2013     | jan 2013      |       2
A110 | jan 2013     | feb 2013      |       1
A111 | feb 2013     | april 2013    |       3
A112 | april 2013   | dec 2013      |       1
```

So everything looks good except the `month_joined` column is duplicated for any patient that has had an appointment during more than one month, making it so if I want the count of the `month_joined`, it's bigger than it should be.

How do I go about calculating the accurate count of `month_joined` while still having the information on the month of each appointment and number of appointments per month?

Comment: [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097)

Comment: Mysql and snowflake are two different products.

Comment: @Shadow alright dude sorry i ruined the feng shui of stack overflow with my one incorrect tag

Comment: Mysql and snowflake each implement sql differently. A code for one may not work for the other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output it seems the tables are joined only on `ID` column. to get the number of rows "duplicated" from table patients windowed COUNT could be used:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY p.ID, p.month_joined) AS number_of_appts
FROM Patients p
LEFT JOIN Appointments a
  ON p.ID = a.ID
```

Comment: Thank you Lukasz! I didn't know PARTITION BY was a clause in SQL